# Linq query to filter out list of list without using Remove

Tags: c#, linq

I still don't have a good grasp on LINQ yet, and felt like my code could be optimized so looking for help.
Bellow is my model

```
class entity
{
    public string id  { get; set; }
    public string catagory { get; set; }
    public IList<details> info{ get; set;}
}
class details
{ 
    public string id{ get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string locale { get; set; }
}   

List<entity> list = new List<entity>();
list.Add(new entity { id = "1", catagory = "cat1", info = new { locale = "en", name = "d1" }, {  locale = "fr", name = "d2" } });
list.Add(new entity { id = "2", catagory = "cat2", info = new { locale = "en", name = "d3" }});
```

Need to filter out based on locale , suppose i need to get only  locale = "en" list ..

model in json for clarity

```
     { 
      "id": "1",
      "catagory": "cat1",
      "info": [{"locale":"en","name":"d1"},{"locale":"fr","name":"d1"}]
    },
    { 
      "id": "2",
      "catagory": "cat2",
      "info": [{"locale":"en","name":"d3"}]
    }
```

expected result-  get only  locale = "en"

```
     { 
      "id": "1",
      "catagory": "cat1",
      "info": [{"locale":"en","name":"d1"}]
    },
    { 
      "id": "2",
      "catagory": "cat2",
      "info": [{"locale":"en","name":"d3"}]
    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linq only solution will be:

```
var result = list.Select(item => new entity
        {
            id = item.id,
            catagory = item.catagory,
            info = item.info.Where(inner => inner.locale == "en").ToList()
        });
```

If you do not want to project new `entry` details then use a `foreach` loop and in it for each item keep only the `details` that match:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    item.info = item.info.Where(inner => inner.locale == "en").ToList();
}
```

---

*Notice that your classes do not follow C#'s naming conventions:*

- [General Naming Conventions - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions)

Comment: @mohd - Glad it helped you, and thanks for marking as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this ... hope it help you ( fixed also some code of yours):

```
 class entity
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string catagory { get; set; }
            public IList<details> info { get; set; }
        }
        class details
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string locale { get; set; }
        }

 List<entity> list = new List<entity>();
            list.Add(new entity { id = "1", catagory = "cat1", info = new List<details> { new details { locale = "en", name = "d1" }, new details { locale = "fr", name = "d2" } } });
            list.Add(new entity { id = "2", catagory = "cat2", info = new List<details> { new details { locale = "en", name = "d3" } } });

            var result = list.Where(xx => xx.info.Any(yy => yy.locale == ""));
```